# resizing JDialog box

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm having trouble with a dialog I created. It packs everything in cutting off border titles and input boxes. I've tried setting the size of the panel and of the components, but to no avail; size never changes. Any help would be appreciated in being able to modify the dimensions of the dialog.

```
JTextField account = new JTextField(6);
account.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(6));
account.setBorder(new TitledBorder("account"));

String[] firstDigitList = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
JComboBox firstDigitCombo = new JComboBox(firstDigitList);
firstDigitCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
firstDigitCombo.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Leading Digit Change"));

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(account);
panel.add(firstDigitCombo);

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Please Enter Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: is this the real code or are you doing some LayoutManager code as well ?

Comment: I suggest not using JOptionPane as this widgets does some automatic sizing depending on e.g. the passed string. I had good results using the Netbeans gui designer. In your case a JDialog based gui would do the job.

Comment: real code. User selects a file and based on the file a jdialog is displayed. I have a few other components added to the panel, but left them out to save space on post.

Comment: BTW.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). ;)

Comment: a) don't use TitledBorder, they add visual clutter and are notoriously difficult to align. Instead use something like a TitledSeparator (part of SwingX, but easy enough to create manually) b) Layout problems are to be solved by ... LayoutManagers. Here you rely on the panel's default, which sizes everything to its prefSize, so there is no resizing to be expected. Instead, use a more powerful manager which allows to fine tune sizing and locating of components

Comment: @kleopatra  I was feeling very 'dirty' as I adjusted the look of the UI to accommodate the `TitledBorder`.  It all felt like a 'kludge to work around a bug'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that a `TitledBorder` will not expand a component to the point where it will be big enough to display the entire text.  Instead it will just truncate the text.

The solution is to ensure the components are big enough for the text to display.  I have shown this here by expanding the size of the text field, and by adding a 'full length' label in placed of the 'shortened' title.

[image: Test Size Of Gui]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class TestSizeOfGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JTextField account = new JTextField(10);
                JPanel accountPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                accountPanel.add(account);
                accountPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Account"));

                String[] firstDigitList = {
                    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

                JLabel firstDigitListLabel = new JLabel("Leading Digit Change");
                JPanel firstDigitListPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,2));
                firstDigitListPanel.add(firstDigitListLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
                JComboBox firstDigitCombo = new JComboBox(firstDigitList);
                firstDigitListPanel.add(firstDigitCombo);
                firstDigitCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
                firstDigitListPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("LDC"));

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(accountPanel);
                panel.add(firstDigitListPanel);

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    null,
                    panel,
                    "Please Enter Values",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 learning item on this day ???? basic problem is that a TitledBorder ??? so strange this JPanel

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I wanted to do. Just learned a whole new way to manipulate JDialog. Oh boy so much more to learn and do! Thanks again!

Comment: nice example to see why _not_ to use TitledBorder :-)

Comment: @mKorbel nothing wrong with the TitledBorder: Borders have _no notion_ of sizing hints. Though the TitledBorder even _does_ have a getMinimumSize which is nowhere used for obvious reasons ;-)